# Android rooted mobile phone root status

Tags: java, android, root

I need a logic for my Android apk, if a mobile is rooted then it should show a pop up to user that ur using rooted device and exit the apk. Some one help TIA..

Comment: Yep...Thank you very much it worked

Answer (score 1):

First implement below library in gradle,

```
implementation 'com.scottyab:rootbeer-lib:0.0.7'
```

And run below code to check if device is root or not.

```
RootBeer rootBeer = new RootBeer(context);
if (rootBeer.isRooted()) {
    //we found indication of root
} else {
    //we didn't find indication of root
}
```

Source : [Git](https://github.com/scottyab/rootbeer)

Comment: If you got your solution from this answer then accept it. I'll appreciate that.

Comment: @Testing Nope. you haven't. Refer [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) to mark it as accepted answer.

Comment: It's worked.  I also had a payment related app, where I need to check root status of app. I surprised that why this answer is not marked as accepted nor voted up till yet.